# TypeError: test_custom_function.<locals>.<lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: '_'

Tags: python, mocking

Having a Python functions as below:

```
def get_student_id():
    while True:
        try:
            print("ENTER STUDENT ID: ")
            identity = int(input())
            if identity > 0:
                return identity
            else:
                print("That's not a natural number. Try again: ")
        except ValueError:
            print("That's not an integer. Try again: ")
```

and

```
def test_get_student_id():
    with mock.patch.object(builtins, 'input', lambda _: '19'):
        assert get_student_id() == '19'
```

Run pytest command to receive an error: TypeError: test_GetStudentId..() missing 1 required positional argument: '_'

Please help to fix above error. Thanks.

Comment: `identity = int(input("ENTER STUDENT ID: "))`? Or `with mock.patch.object(builtins, 'input', lambda: '19'):`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling *input* you're passing no arguments (`input()`), but you're telling *unittest.mock* that it has one (`lambda _:`).
You need to be consistent. **Either**:

1. Pass one argument when calling it

   ```py
   identity = int(input("ENTER STUDENT ID: ")
   ```
2. Instruct *unittest.mock* that function is called with no arguments

   ```py
   mock.patch.object(builtins, 'input', lambda: '19')
   ```

From my *PoV*, the former makes more sense, as you could also get rid of the *print* statement before.